# How to motion track green screen footage and paint out the tracking markers

Tags: workflow

I've been trying my hands at VFX within Blender for the past couple of days. I've got a few clips that have been shot against a green screen with tracking markers. I looked at a couple of tutorials and learned how to key the green screen and motion track. However, I couldn't get rid of the tracking markers - I tried masking them out but to no avail. I thought it would be pretty straight forward but I guess I was wrong. One of the reasons could be that I'm not used to the node based compositing inside Blender.

How would you go about doing what I'm struggling with. This is the sequence of how I am trying to achieve this.

1. Import the green screen footage inside the video editor and export a png sequence.
2. Start a new project. Reimport the png sequence inside Blender and track the markers within the footage.
3. Key the green screen out.

What do I do next ? I tried creating a couple of masks that covered a number of static tracking markers but I can't seem to get rid of them. I also tried opening the same image sequence inside the Editing tab after having done all this and connected the mask to an adjustment layer - I can see that the markers have disappeared in the Video Editing workspace but it doesn't show up in the compositing window. This makes me really confused - Why do I have to reimport the video in the Editing tab when it's already open in the Motion tracking tab ?

Again, let's say that I successfully key the green screen and remove the tracking markers. I suppose I should stay within this project file if I want to add 3D models around the footage. Am I right ?

I am a complete noob so I would really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Mask the tracking markers? They are a UI element and would NEVER show up in the final render. I think you’re sneaking up on a boomerang.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear while phrasing my question. The markers are on the green screen itself. I found a few tutorials on Youtube explaining how to remove them but I already have a garbage mask removing unnecessary elements from the footage. I created a couple of more masks trying to mask out the tracking markers on the green screen but I was simply lost trying to figure out which node goes where inside the compositor.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I found a solution to my problem by creating masks and combining them with a Mix node. Plugging the mix node into the garbage matte of the Keying node gets rid of the markers on the green screen. The difficult part is to keyframe the masks one by one but it's alright since I know it will get the job done.

However I am wondering if there's a smarter way to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with a green and blue screen in the same shot, then try this:

Key out the green screen like normal.
Use a keying node again, but this time for the blue tracking markers.
Ta-da!

Of course, your actors can't wear green **or blue**, so that might cause more problems than it's worth.